# Did King David Expose himself (nude) while dancing or was it just unfit for him in the eyes of Michal

Tags: clothing, samuel-shmuel-book-of, king-david

As the title, in Book 2 of Shmuel Chapter 6 it says that Michal peered through her window and saw King David dancing and loathed him for doing so: "And David danced with all his might before the Lord; and David was girded with a linen ephod.       ידוְדָוִד מְכַרְכֵּר בְּכָל עֹז לִפְנֵי יְהֹוָה וְדָוִד חָגוּר אֵפוֹד בָּד:
15And David and all the house of Israel brought up the ark of the Lord with shouting and with the sound of [the] shofar.        טווְדָוִד וְכָל בֵּית יִשְׂרָאֵל מַעֲלִים אֶת אֲרוֹן יְהֹוָה בִּתְרוּעָה וּבְקוֹל שׁוֹפָר:
16And [as] the ark of the Lord came [into] the city of David, Michal the daughter of Saul peered through the window, and she saw the king David hopping and dancing before the Lord; and she loathed him in her heart." and she goes on to greet him later and rebuke him for doing so and then tells him ""How honored was today the king of Israel, who exposed himself today in the eyes of the handmaids of his servants, as would expose himself one of the idlers."

Did King David Expose himself (nude) while dancing or was it just unfit for him in the eyes of Michal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The commentators (drawing on traditional sources) like Rashi and Metzudos, etc., explain that David put on a linen casual robe used by celebrants that would honor a religious event. He was covering most of his body, but as he danced vigorously, his legs and arms were exposed. It does not mean that he was naked in the "total" sense. The robe was nice, but it was far from the conservative and dignified king's attire, which would usually cover his arms and legs fully and at all times.

Imagine someone entering a Whitehouse press conference with a t-shirt and half-pants. That's what Michal felt her husband looked like. She really wanted the business suit and tie look instead.

:)